# Promise chaining with functions

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am trying to use promises for a small new project. But I have some problems with understanding how I could organize my code better, with functions. Problem is, I want my functions to handle things, and my main code to handle other things. So let's see this code:

```
function doSomething (isGoingToResolve = true) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (isGoingToResolve) {
        resolve("something")
    } else {
        reject("something else")
    }
  }).then(response => {
    console.log("in my function",response)
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log("in my function",error)
  })
}

doSomething().then(response => {
    console.log("in my main call", response)
})
```

With this code, the console will log `in my function something` and `in my main call undefined`: https://jsfiddle.net/hkacvw2g/

So I found two solutions to solve my problem, but I just don't like them:

The first one is to create a variable, use a `.then()` on the variable, and then return the variable (https://jsfiddle.net/hkacvw2g/1/):

```
function doSomething (isGoingToResolve = true) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (isGoingToResolve) {
        resolve("something")
    } else {
        reject("something else")
    }
  })

  promise.then(response => {
    console.log("in my function",response)
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log("in my function",error)
  })

  return promise
}
```

And the second solution (https://jsfiddle.net/hkacvw2g/2/):

```
function doSomething (isGoingToResolve = true) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (isGoingToResolve) {
        resolve("something")
    } else {
        reject("something else")
    }
  }).then(response => {
    console.log("in my function",response)
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(response)
    })
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log("in my function",error)
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        reject(error)
    })
  })
}
```

**Am I missing a better solution to solve my problem?**

Comment: Off topic. I recommend you to read about promise antipatterns. Rule of thumb: you hardly ever need to use `Promise` constructor manually in your code.  http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the link, I am actually using `mysql-promise` npm package but I wanted to make my question more generic

Comment: You may want to check out this article about promise chaining, which helped me wrapping my head around this topic. http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply return the value (or re-throw the error) and it will be resolved in promise chain:

```
function doSomething (isGoingToResolve = true) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (isGoingToResolve) {
      resolve("something")
    } else {
      reject("something else")
    }
  }).then(response => {
    console.log("in my function",response)
    return response;
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log("in my function",error)
    throw error;
  })
}
```

You might not want that `throw error`, it depends on how you want to handle your rejections. This way when you re-throw the error, you should catch it when calling the `doSomething()` method.

Comment: It was as simple as that, thank you! (will accept after the 10 minutes obligation)

Comment: Actually, I like his first solution better. It's more robust. It lessens the risk of messing up the promise chain by inadvertently forgetting to return the original value from `then` clauses meant only for logging.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `tap` function, to tap into a promise chain, and do something while passing along the result, and a parallel `tapCatch` function, to tap into errors while rethrowing them:

```
const tap      = fn => value  => { fn(value);  return value; };
const tapCatch = fn => reason => { fn(reason); throw reason; };
```

Now you can write your code as:

```
function doSomething(isGoingToResolve = true) {
  (isGoingToResolve ? 
    Promise.resolve("something") : 
    Promise.reject("something else")
  )
  .then( tap     (response => console.log("in my function", response)))
  .catch(tapCatch(error    => console.log("in my function", error)));
}

doSomething()
  .then(response => console.log("in my main call", response));
```

However, actually your first solution is better. It reduces the risk of messing up the promise chain by inadvertently forgetting to, or not realizing that you have to, return the original value in `then` clauses, or rethrow in `catch` clauses which such clauses are meant only for logging purposes or other side-effects.

You could also pollute the `Promise` prototype with something like `tap` (we'll call it `thenDo`), making it a bit easier to use:

```
Promise.prototype.thenDo = function(ifFulfilled, ifRejected) {
  return this.then(
    value => { ifFulfilled(value); return value; },
    reason => { ifRejected(reason); throw reason; });
};
Promise.prototype.catchDo = function(ifRejected) {
  return this.catch(reason => { ifRejected(reason); throw reason; });
};
```

Now you can write

```
function doSomething(isGoingToResolve = true) {
  (isGoingToResolve ? 
    Promise.resolve("something") : 
    Promise.reject("something else")
  )
  .thenDo (response => console.log("in my function", response))
  .catchDo(error    => console.log("in my function", error));
}
```